# Helath check in python script

Tags: python, loops, notifications, python-multithreading

I have a script that sniffs incoming emails from mailbox (based on outlooks events, not active scanning) and based on condition it does it's things. Now this should be ran unsupervised, but i would like to have some kind of health check that would notify me that script is not dead.

I cannot use threads (threading.Timer), because even if main dies, the second one will work
I cannot use while (because it will repet whole code, resetting conditions, or just some code blocking execution of the other part - or i am wrong?)
I also cannot use time.sleep because of code block.

Is there any way to run timer only if main script works without blocking?

it did not worked or i cannot implement it properly. In my code the async function is run only once despite while loop

```
import datetime
import win32com.client
import datetime as dt
import pythoncom
import pytz
import pymsteams
import smtplib
import asyncio


def file_reader(path):
    try:
        with open(path, "rt") as file:
            _ = file.read()
            _ = _.split(",")
            return _
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("error, file was not found")
        return []


def notification_engine(message):
    connector = pymsteams.connectorcard("Tems_webhook",
                                        https_proxy="proxy_server",
                                        verify=r"some cert")
    connector.title("app alert")
    connector.color("FF0000")
    connector.text(message)
    connector.send()


def email_fallback_notification(body, sender="some@email",reciver = "some@email"):
    message = f"Subject: Online Onboarding alert Fallback notification\n\n{body}"

try:
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp_server")
    smtp.sendmail(sender, reciver, message)
    print("done, email sent")
except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
    print(e)


def proxy_refresh():
url = "https://www.google.dk"
com_obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
com_obj.SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)
com_obj.Open("GET", url, False)
com_obj.Send()


def email_parser(email_list, local_time, filter_list, ID, message, timeout=60, email_count=2):
    #some email logic


'''Event listeners classes for each mailbox'''


class AppHandler(object):  # event listener
    def __init__(self):
        self.email_list = []  # creates empty list where emails will be stored
        self.local = pytz.timezone(
            'utc')  # to overcome timezone issues we need to convert locla time to be timezone aware'
        self.app_list = file_reader(
            path=r"some\path")  # initiate a list
        # with errors that should be checked in subject
        # timezone time

    def OnItemAdd(self, item):  # event fired once email lands in folder
        email_parser(email_list=self.email_list, local_time=self.local, ID=item, filter_list=self.app_list,
                     message="alert. Please check the mailbox", timeout=60, email_count=5)


session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session  # dispaching outlook sessions
shared_inbox_of_oo_alerts = session.Folders.Item(r"1st level folder").Folders.Item(
r"2nd level folder")


async def health_check():
    try:
        print("health check")
        notification_engine(f"Health check done, script running {datetime.datetime.now()}  ")
        await asyncio.sleep(6)
    except OSError:
        proxy_refresh()
        notification_engine("Health check done, script running")


async def main():
    _ = asyncio.create_task(health_check())


'''inboxes of the online onbaording, to be sued with Event listeners'''
Some_INBOX = shared_inbox_of_some_app.Folders.Item("some_app")

'''Events Handlers instantiate '''
# TODO: Add rest of the instances of the Event Handlers
outlook = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents(Some_INBOX.Items,
                                               AppHandler)  # send events to listener(AppHandler)

asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.run(main())
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: You say `time.sleep` blocks. Have you considered the non-blocking version, `asyncio.sleep`?

Comment: it did not worked or i cannot implement it properly. In my code the async function is run only once despite while loop